# sympy TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to calculate integration using sympy, here is my code:

```
import sympy as sp
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math
def f(x):
    return math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*sp.I*x*n)
x = sp.Symbol('x')
n = sp.Symbol('n')
res,err = quad(f,0,1)
print(res)
```

It gives me `TypeError: can't convert expression to float` inside f(x), **how can I solve this ?**

**Trying to solve this : Integration of `e^(-2*pi*n*I*x)` in range of 0 to 1 with respect to x**

Doesn't support math ajax : $$\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi inx} dx$$

if I just write `math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*x)` it works, but if I write `math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*sp.I)` or `math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*n)` it doesn't or for other combinations.

Comment: if I just write `math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*x)` it works, but if I write `math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*sp.I)` or `math.exp(-2.0*math.pi*n)` it doesn't or for other combinations. @JohanC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sympy can not work with math imports, you need specific sympy functions. Neither do sympy and scipy play together well.

A pure sympy solution:

```py
import sympy as sp

def f(x):
    return sp.exp(-2.0*sp.pi*sp.I*x*n)

x = sp.Symbol('x')
n = sp.Symbol('n')

res = sp.integrate(f(x), (x, 0, 1))
```

Output:

```py
Piecewise((-0.5*I/(pi*n) + 0.5*I*exp(-2.0*I*pi*n)/(pi*n), (n > -oo) & (n < oo) & Ne(n, 0)), (1, True))
```

Use `n = sp.Symbol('n', nonzero=True)` if you know `n` will never be zero, which simplifies the output to just `-0.5*I/(pi*n) + 0.5*I*exp(-2.0*I*pi*n)/(pi*n)`

Afterwards, you can use sympy's [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to convert the result to a normal python function of `n`.

Comment: it works, I will except in 10 minutes, now tell me - **`def f(x,n):    return sp.exp(-2.0*sp.pi*sp.I*x*n)*(x**(2/3) + (1-x*x)**(1/2))    x = sp.Symbol('x') res = sp.integrate(f(x,i), (x, 0, 1))`** , why this doesn't work??

Comment: @JohaC here : https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/78d15e39c3b4ff74aca06e52813f19f1#file-sympy_test-py

Comment: Because i is not defined there. You need to define `i` just like you did with `n` before.

Comment: that would be 1

Comment: it gives me **Integral((x**0.666666666666667 + (1 - x**2)**0.5)*exp(-2.0*I*pi*x), (x, 0, 1))** actually what I gave to it

Comment: This probably means that sympy can not calculate that integral. Maybe try with wolframalpha to get more information about your integral

Comment: is there any other way to calculate integration like this ??

Comment: wolframalpha says "Standard computation time exceeded..."